# Save all Shapes of slide into single JPG image

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

I have a small tool to export the pictures inside ppt documents to image files, so I can import them somewhere else.
For this, I have been using the following piece of code:

```
For Each slideShape In slide
    If slideShape.Type = msoPicture Then
        Call slideShape.Export(materialPresentation.Path & "\" & ecode & "_" & cont & ".jpg", ppSaveAsJPG)
        cont = cont + 1
    End If
Next slideShape
```

However, in a different tool, I am required to export all the shapes of a slide at once, exactly like selecting them with the mouse, and clicking in "Save as image", which creates an image with all the shapes.

Is there a way to do it using VBA? All I found online were examples of exporting single shapes (Which I already know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the shapes you want to export then export the resulting group shape.

Answer (score 0):

What may also work is exporting via ShapeRange (`slide` is a `Slide` object), e.g.

```
slide.Shapes.Range().Export("C:\output.jpg", ppShapeFormatJPG)
```