# PPT VBA: Capturing Screen Shot inside Shape

Tags: vba, export, jpeg, powerpoint, shapes

I'm fairly new to VBA coding. I am trying to capture a photo from a slide. The photo is outlined by a rectangle. There are text boxes and arrows inside the rectangle that I am trying to capture. I know I can group the object and export the shape as the group. It would be better for my situation if it was not necessary to group the objects. The current code does save a photo of the rectangle, but not the other shapes on top of it.

```
Dim photoA As Variant

Set photoA = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("Rectangle 2")

With photoA
    .Export "A.jpg", ppShapeFormatJPG
End With
```

Comment: What difficulties is the grouping causing there?  Otherwise, you have to loop over each shape in the collection to export I believe.  This example may help going that route, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427404/save-all-shapes-of-slide-into-single-jpg-image

Comment: There is also a photo being placed behind the rectangle that extends beyond the border of the rectangle. I would rather not crop the photo to fit inside the rectangle.

Comment: The linked example does the same thing my code does. I am still unable to screen shot the area inside the shape.